# Как применить копию шаблона из папки local?

Tags: битрикс

я скопировал шаблон сайта из /bitrix/templates в /local/templates,изменил название и описание,но он почему то не появляется в списке шаблонов в админке,чтобы я мог его применить

Answer (score 0):

Название и описание изменили в файле description.php?

Попробуйте папку с шаблоном переименовать.